MySQL8 ORDER BY with JOIN uses filesort even though the result set is sorted already (based on indexes)
Table schemas:
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `fieldToFilterBy` int NOT NULL,
  `someKindOfInt` int NOT NULL,
  `fieldToJoinOn` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fieldToFilterBy`,`someKindOfInt`),
  UNIQUE KEY `intexOfTable1` (`fieldToFilterBy`,`fieldToJoinOn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `fieldToJoinOn` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fieldToSortBy` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fieldToSortBy`),
  UNIQUE KEY `indexOfTable2` (`fieldToJoinOn`,`fieldToSortBy`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

The query:
SELECT t1.fieldToFilterBy, t1.someKindOfInt, t1.fieldToJoinOn, t2.fieldToSortBy
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.fieldToJoinOn = t2.fieldToJoinOn
WHERE t1.fieldToFilterBy = 123
ORDER BY <....>
LIMIT 100;

If for the ORDER BY <...> I use:

t1.fieldToFilterBy - it uses index
t2.fieldToFilterBy - the execution plan contains filesort even though the result set is already sorted and the field contains the same values as the field in the previous example
t1/2.fieldToFilterBy, t2.fieldToSortBy - I'm interested in this one. The execution plan contains filesort even though the result set is already sorted (it uses the indexOfTable2 for join, taking into account how the nested loop inner join works and my own tests - it's always sorted)

I'm concerned about the filesort in the case 3 above. I found out that MySQL uses Quicksort or Merge sort for filesort, but no details about the implementation (seems like it can be very inefficient in some implementations, even if the array is sorted). + it creates a temporary  table for sorting. I don't want to rely on the fact that it returns a sorted set of rows even without the ORDER BY clause, since the result is used for pagination.
Is there a way to help the MySQL understand that no sorting is required? Or am I missing something? Thank you!
Tried forcing indexes and using subselects, it didn't help

A table in a relational data base has NO intrinsic order to it.  None. Primary key - doesn't  matter. Table indexes - doesn't matter.  You, the user, have no access to the actual organization of the table in the data base. If your particular data base implementation happens to return records in a particular order, that is an accident that could change with the next release.

for others looking at this, would be nice to have the question give the full version (output of select version())

Generally spoken: If you want your result to be sorted, you always have to use an ORDER BY clause. There are no excpetions for this rule. MySQL and also other RDBMS often return rows sorted as the user expects although they didn't tell the RDBMS to do so, but that's just luck.

If you don't know this you should: ^filesort^ is not a great name for it. It means that the query planner creates an intermediate  result set that it  then sorts. It doesn't necessarily  spill to any kind of backing store  on the file system. It isn't as disastrous performance-wise as it  sounds.

MySQL always reads tables via some index (assuming InnoDB, the default storage engine).
If the order you request in your ORDER BY clause is the same as the order of the index the optimizer chooses, then there will be no Using filesort needed.
But this only works for the first joined table.
If you request an order by some column from any table after the first joined table, then MySQL must do a filesort, because it can't assume it will read rows sequentially, even though it uses an index to look up the rows.
Note that the first joined table isn't necessarily the first table you name in your query. The optimizer can reorder tables in some cases. The real first joined table is the one listed on the first line of the EXPLAIN report.
